# Retrofit returns null for value from json key though it has response android

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, android-livedata

I have json response like this.

```
{
  "movies": [
    {
      "Title": "Avengers:Age of Ultron ",
      "Year": "2015 ",
      "Rated": "PG-13 ",
      "Released": "01 May 2015 ",
      "Runtime": "141 min ",
      "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi ",
      "Director": "Joss Whedon ",
      "Writer": "Joss Whedon, Stan Lee (based on the Marvel comics by), Jack Kirby (based on the Marvel comics by), Joe Simon (character created by: Captain America), Jack Kirby (character created by: Captain America), Jim Starlin (character created by: Thanos) ",
      "Actors": "Robert Downey Jr., Chris Hemsworth, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Evans ",
      "Plot": "When Tony Stark and Bruce Banner try to jump-start a dormant peacekeeping program called Ultron, things go horribly wrong and it's up to Earth's mightiest heroes to stop the villainous Ultron from enacting his terrible plan. ",
      "Language": "English, Korean ",
      "Country": "USA ",
      "Awards": "7 wins \u0026 45 nominations."
    },
    {
      "Title": "TheAvengers ",
      "Year": "2012 ",
      "Rated": "PG-13 ",
      "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi ",
      "Actors": "Robert Downey Jr., Chris Evans, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Hemsworth ",
      "Plot": "Earth's mightiest heroes must come together and learn to fight as a team if they are going to stop the mischievous Loki and his alien army from enslaving humanity. ",
      "Language": "English, Russian, Hindi ",
      "Country": "USA ",
      **"Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg ",**
      "Released": "04 May 2012 ",
      "Runtime": "143 min ",
      "Director": "Joss Whedon ",
      "Writer": "Joss Whedon (screenplay), Zak Penn (story), Joss Whedon (story) ",
      "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 38 wins \u0026 79 nominations. "
    },
    {
      "Title": "Sleepless ",
      "Year": "2017 ",
      "Rated": "R ",
      "Released": "13Jan 2017 ",
      "Runtime": "95 min ",
      "Genre": "Action, Crime, Thriller ",
      "Director": "Baran bo Odar ",
      "Writer": "Andrea Berloff (screenplay by), Frédéric Jardin (based on the film    Nuit blanche written by), Nicolas Saada (based on the film Nuit blanche written by), Olivier Douyère (based on the film    Nuit blanche   written by)",
      "Actors": "Jamie Foxx, Michelle Monaghan, Scoot McNairy, Dermot Mulroney ",
      "Plot": "A cop with a connection to the criminal underworld scours a nightclub in search of his kidnapped son. ",
      "Language": "English ",
      "Country": "USA ",
      "Awards": "1 nomination. ",
      **"Poster ": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjEwMDAyOTM4OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzc4MjMyMDI@._V1_SX300.jpg "**
    },
    {
      "Title": "TheDark Knight ",
      "Year": "2008 ",
      "Rated": "PG-13 ",
      "Released": "18 Jul 2008 ",
      "Runtime": "152 min ",
      "Genre": "Action, Crime, Drama ",
      "Director": "Christopher Nolan ",
      "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (story), David S. Goyer (story), Bob Kane (characters) ",
      "Actors": "Christian Bale, Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine ",
      "Plot": "When the menace known as the Joker emerges from his mysterious past, he wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham. The Dark Knight must accept one of the greatest psychological and physical tests of his ability to fight injustice. ",
      "Language": "English, Mandarin ",
      "Country": "USA, UK ",
      "Awards": "Won 2 Oscars. Another 152 wins \u0026 155 nominations. ",
      **"Poster ": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg "**
    },
    {
      "Title": "SavingPrivate Ryan ",
      "Year": "1998 ",
      "Rated": "R ",
      "Released": "24 Jul 1998 ",
      "Runtime": "169 min ",
      "Genre": "Drama, War ",
      "Director": "Steven Spielberg ",
      "Writer": "Robert Rodat ",
      "Actors": "Tom Hanks, Tom Sizemore, Edward Burns, Barry Pepper ",
      "Plot": "Following the Normandy Landings, a group of U.S. soldiers go behind enemy lines to retrieve a paratrooper whose brothers have been killed in action. ",
      "Language": "English, French, German, Czech ",
      "Country": "USA ",
      "Awards": "Won 5 Oscars. Another 74 wins \u0026 74 nominations. ",
      **"Poster ": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjhkMDM4MWItZTVjOC00ZDRhLThmYTAtM2I5NzBmNmNlMzI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDYyMDk5MTU@._V1_SX300.jpg "**
    },
    {
      "Plot": "Moirac, a notary, and Landron, a retired army surgeon, who have been friends since boyhood, live in the same village. The daughter of the notary is, at the same time, the god-child of the...",
      "Title": "Fatherand God Father ",
      "Year": "1912 ",
      "Rated": "N/A ",
      "Released": "27 Feb 1913 ",
      "Runtime": "N/A ",
      "Genre": "Short, Comedy ",
      "Director": "N/A ",
      "Writer": "N/A ",
      "Actors": "N/A ",
      "Language": "French ",
      "Country": "France ",
      "Awards": "N/A ",
      **"Poster ": "N/A ",**
      "Ratings ": "",
      "Metascore ": "N/A ",
      "imdbRating ": "N/A ",
      "imdbVotes ": "N/A ",
      "imdbID ": "tt1318958 ",
      "Type ": "movie ",
      "DVD ": "N/A ",
      "BoxOffice ": "N/A ",
      "Production ": "N/A ",
      "Website ": "N/A ",
      "Response ": "True "
    }
```

In the above json response, you can see the "Poster" json key is not present in first data set whereas it is present in second data set, similarly for some it comes as null.

Now problem is, when I am using in Retrofit, only one data from Poster, it returns whereas for all other, it display as **null** Issue is coming only for Poster

Below is the class how I done.

```
public class Movies {
    @SerializedName("Released")
    private String Released;
    @SerializedName("Plot")
    private String Plot;
    @SerializedName("Director")
    private String Director;
    @SerializedName("Title")
    private String Title;
    @SerializedName("Actors")
    private String Actors;
    @SerializedName("Runtime")
    private String Runtime;
    @SerializedName("Awards")
    private String Awards;
    @SerializedName("Year")
    private String Year;
    @SerializedName("Language")
    private String Language;
    @SerializedName("Rated")
    private String Rated;
    @SerializedName("Country")
    private String Country;
    @SerializedName("Genre")
    private String Genre;
    @SerializedName("Writer")
    private String Writer;
    @SerializedName("Poster")
    @Expose
    private String Poster;

    public String getPoster() {
        return Poster;
    }

    public void setPoster(String Poster) {
        this.Poster = Poster;
    }

    public String getReleased() {
        return Released;
    }

    public void setReleased(String Released) {
        this.Released = Released;
    }

    public String getPlot() {
        return Plot;
    }

    public void setPlot(String Plot) {
        this.Plot = Plot;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return Director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String Director) {
        this.Director = Director;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        this.Title = Title;
    }

    public String getActors() {
        return Actors;
    }

    public void setActors(String Actors) {
        this.Actors = Actors;
    }

    public String getRuntime() {
        return Runtime;
    }

    public void setRuntime(String Runtime) {
        this.Runtime = Runtime;
    }

    public String getAwards() {
        return Awards;
    }

    public void setAwards(String Awards) {
        this.Awards = Awards;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return Year;
    }

    public void setYear(String Year) {
        this.Year = Year;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return Language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String Language) {
        this.Language = Language;
    }

    public String getRated() {
        return Rated;
    }

    public void setRated(String Rated) {
        this.Rated = Rated;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String Country) {
        this.Country = Country;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return Genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String Genre) {
        this.Genre = Genre;
    }

    public String getWriter() {
        return Writer;
    }

    public void setWriter(String Writer) {
        this.Writer = Writer;
    }
```

The above is the pojo class where I specified as SerializedName for poster.

Now in Retrofit,

```
public class MoviesRepository {
    private static MoviesRepository moviesRepository;
    private MovieApiInterface newsApi;
    public static Application application;

    public static MoviesRepository getInstance() {
        if (moviesRepository == null) {
            moviesRepository = new MoviesRepository(application);
        }
        return moviesRepository;
    }



    public MoviesRepository(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
        newsApi = RetrofitService.cteateService(MovieApiInterface.class);
    }

public MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> getMovieUpdates() {
    final MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> moviesData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    newsApi.getMovieDetails().enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if(response.body()!=null) {
                    moviesData.setValue(response.body());
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("RETROFIT RESPONSE", "Failure"+call.toString());
            Log.i("RETROFIT RESPONSE", "Failure"+t);
           // moviesData.setValue(null);

        }
    });
    return moviesData;
}
```

Here in response, when I see, I get the datas for first but all other response, the poster is coming as null.

When I debug and checked, (I didn't posted fully. I took only the poster)

```
position 1:
Poster = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg "
    position 2:
    Poster = null
    position 3: 
    Poster = null
```

Poster alone is coming as null for all except for **position 1.** when i checked the response.

MoviesResponse:

```
 public class MovieResponse implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("movies")
    private List<Movies> movies;

    public List<Movies> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }

    public void setMovies(List<Movies> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }
}
```

MoviesViewModel:

```
 public class MoviesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> mutableLiveData;
    private MoviesRepository moviesRepository;

    public MoviesViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        moviesRepository = new MoviesRepository(application);
    }

    public void init() {
        if (mutableLiveData != null) {
            return;
        }
        moviesRepository = MoviesRepository.getInstance();
        mutableLiveData = moviesRepository.getMovieUpdates();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> getNewsRepository() {
        return moviesRepository.getMovieUpdates();
    }
}
```

RetrofitService:

```
public class RetrofitService {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    public static <S> S cteateService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}



public class MoviesRepository {
    private static MoviesRepository moviesRepository;
    private MovieApiInterface newsApi;
    public static Application application;

    public static MoviesRepository getInstance() {
        if (moviesRepository == null) {
            moviesRepository = new MoviesRepository(application);
        }
        return moviesRepository;
    }



    public MoviesRepository(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
        newsApi = RetrofitService.cteateService(MovieApiInterface.class);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> getMovieUpdates() {
        final MutableLiveData<MovieResponse> moviesData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        newsApi.getMovieDetails().enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if(response.body()!=null) {
                        moviesData.setValue(response.body());
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("RETROFIT RESPONSE", "Failure"+call.toString());
                Log.i("RETROFIT RESPONSE", "Failure"+t);
               // moviesData.setValue(null);

            }
        });
        return moviesData;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MoviesAdapter newsAdapter;
    RecyclerView rvHeadline;
    MoviesViewModel newsViewModel;
    List<Movies> newsArticles;
    List<Movies> articleArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rvHeadline = findViewById(R.id.rvNews);
         articleArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        newsAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, articleArrayList);
        rvHeadline.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rvHeadline.setAdapter(newsAdapter);

        newsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MoviesViewModel.class);
        newsViewModel.init();
        newsViewModel.getNewsRepository().observe(this, newsResponse -> {

            if (newsResponse != null) {
                newsArticles = newsResponse.getMovies();
                articleArrayList.addAll(newsArticles);
                for(int i=0;i<articleArrayList.size();i++){
                    String poster = articleArrayList.get(i).getPoster();
                    Log.i("poster","poster"+poster);
                }
                newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
       // setupRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        if (newsAdapter == null) {
            newsAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(MainActivity.this, articleArrayList);
            rvHeadline.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            rvHeadline.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
            rvHeadline.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rvHeadline.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        } else {
            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

MoviesAdapter:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<Movies> articles;

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context, List<Movies> articles) {
        this.context = context;
        this.articles = articles;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.movies_item, parent, false);
        return new MoviesViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tvName.setText(articles.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.tvDesCription.setText(articles.get(position).getPoster());
        String url = articles.get(position).getPoster();
        if(url!=null) {
           /* Glide.with(context) //passing context
                    .load(url) //passing your url to load image.
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .placeholder(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                    .centerCrop()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView
                    .into(holder.ivNews);*/ //pass imageView reference to appear the image.*/
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(holder.ivNews);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }

    public class MoviesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvDesCription;
        ImageView ivNews;

        public MoviesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            tvDesCription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesCription);
            ivNews = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivNews);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I see `MovieResponse` class. Also is ** in the json response just your edit?

Comment: @IsraeldelaCruz Sure. I have added the movieresponse class

Comment: All other response are coming correctly except poster.

Comment: Where did you get the json response above? From `response` or from the browser? Did you edit it or just copied it?

Comment: From response @IsraeldelaCruz I don't want to put all json response..so i just copied few and pasted it. This is that url. api.myjson.com/bins/18buhu. You can see poster is missing in first json structure whereas for some poster is displaying. So retrofit is always displaying null for all other positions

Comment: There is no optString too to do in retrofit how we parse the json.

Comment: Why there is need for @Expose for `Poster` key?

Comment: Since poster is not working, so I tried giving expose. But even when I removed @Expose too, it's still not giving the exact url from response.@hemantsb

Comment: I couldn't found any issue with your model. Can you post MovieResponse Model as string so that i can check what values you are getting.

Comment: Yes. I already posted the MovieResponse class.

Comment: I meant MovieResponse model after data is fetched and inserted.

Comment: I updated the MoviesRepository , RetrofitService and MainActivity.

Comment: Still clueless why only poster alone is not working. :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195895/discussion-between-hemantsb-and-star).

Comment: Will you be able to join chat ? i have initiated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Poster" key contains space. "Poster ".
Fix this json Key.

Key should be same to parse. You are trying to parse "Poster" but you are getting "Poster " and "Poster".

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your response object doesn't have that Poster key, like the first object in the example snippet.

Comment: krishnan: Yes, in that case how to handle? Retrofit is always taking null for second, third and all as null datas eventhough data is available for poster (2nd and 3rd). https://api.myjson.com/bins/18buhu

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by return default blank string or default URL. See below example.

**In your model class you have to do it.**

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("Poster")
private String Poster;

public String getPoster() {
   return Poster == null ? "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg" : Poster;
}

public void setPoster(String Poster) {
   this.Poster = Poster;
}
```

In the above code, if your poster key not found in json then you can return **"" or default URL**. if Poster key found at that time it returns its value.

Comment: I am getting crash as Path must not be empty.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)
        at movie.adapter.MoviesAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MoviesAdapter.java:49) I updated the MovieAdapter.

Comment: this crash issue is because we pass a blank string. as I told you to pass default path in picasso.

Comment: Can you please correct the code how I need to update?

Comment: suppose your default path is **"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDYxNjQyMjAtNTdiOS00NGYwLWFmNTAtNThmYjU5ZGI2YTI1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg "**. you have to pass default path when you not get the key **poster** check it. I'm changed the code in model class.